# How can I use reverse relation items in templates django

Tags: django, orm, django-templates

```
 {% for order in orders %}
  <li>{{order.customer.last_name}} - {{ order.orderitem_set.product.unit_price }}</li>
  {% endfor %}

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, 
    decimal_places=2)
    inventory = models.IntegerField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, 
    on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    promotions = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion)

class Order(models.Model):
    placed_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, 
    on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, 
    decimal_places=2)
```

How can I  get products unit_price in browser, last_name shows but when I am trying to use django reverse relation created item the value don't showing

Comment: Share your models as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an order can consist of multiple items you would have to iterate over the set (the reverse relation):

```html
{% for item in order.orderitem_set.all %}
    {{ item.product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Habe a look at the documentation for [querying reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).